# Vue single file component imported scss intellisense

Tags: vue.js, sass, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am playing around with VSCode and vue.
I could use external scss file with some variables in vue sfc through import statement. Everything works fine except that the intellisense does not load the variables in the .vue file.

This is my style tag in the .vue file

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '~styles/main';
$other-color: #FFAAAA;
.greeting {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: $secondary-color;
    border-bottom: 2px solid $primary-color;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
```

$other-color is found by the intellisense but not $primary-color and $secondary-color that are defined in the '~styles/main' (and loaded correctly by webpack).

Am I missing something or it is not possible to make it work?

Comment: Does it work if you add the '.scss' extension in your '@import' declaration ?

Comment: No, i already tried to add the extension. For your information i also installed vetur extension

Comment: Which vue extensions are you using?

Comment: For Vue I am just using vetur extension

Answer (score 1):

I first created a separate .scss file, moved all the component styles there and then I added a reference to the component scss in my vue sfc file.

```
<!-- .vue -->
<template>
<div>
    <div class="greeting">Hello {{name}}{{exclamationMarks}}</div>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
    props: ['name', 'initialEnthusiasm'],
    data() {
        return {
            enthusiasm: this.initialEnthusiasm,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        increment() { this.enthusiasm++; },
        decrement() {
            if (this.enthusiasm > 1) {
                this.enthusiasm--;
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {
        exclamationMarks(): string {
            return Array(this.enthusiasm + 1).join('!');
        }
    }
});
</script>

<style src="./Hello.scss" scoped></style>
```

In this way I have no problems to use variables from imported scss files.

In this example, the *greeting* class is defined in the Hello.scss file. To get the autocomplete of the scss classes in my vue files I use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion) Visual Studio Code extension.